# Share Email Folder Using mdapi

Tags: soap-api, webservices, mdapi

I am using financialforcedev's mdapi to create folder sharing in my Salesforce org - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

I am using the following code for Sharing DashboardFolder which works absolutely fine.

```
 @future(callout=true)
public static void shareDashboardFolder(String brandAPIName, String brandManagerRoleAPIName, String brandAgentAPIName)
{
    // Retrieve Folder
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.DashboardFolder folder = (MetadataService.DashboardFolder) service.readMetadata('DashboardFolder',
                                                                        new String[] { brandAPIName }).getRecords()[0];    
    MetadataService.FolderShare folderShareServiceManager = new MetadataService.FolderShare();        
    MetadataService.FolderShare folderShareService = new MetadataService.FolderShare();
    folderShareService.accessLevel = 'View';
    folderShareService.sharedTo = brandAPIName;
    folderShareService.sharedToType = 'Role';
    System.debug('Dashboard Folder :::::: '+folder);
    folder.folderShares.add(folderShareService);        
    service.updateMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { folder });         
}
```

However, when I try doing the same using EmailFolder, I get a null pointer exception on line - folder.folderShares.add(folderShareService);

```
      @future(callout=true)
public static void shareDashboardFolder(String brandAPIName, String brandManagerRoleAPIName, String brandAgentAPIName)
{
    // Retrieve Folder
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.EmailFolder folder = (MetadataService.EmailFolder) service.readMetadata('EmailFolder',
                                                                        new String[] { brandAPIName }).getRecords()[0];    
    MetadataService.FolderShare folderShareServiceManager = new MetadataService.FolderShare();        
    MetadataService.FolderShare folderShareService = new MetadataService.FolderShare();
    folderShareService.accessLevel = 'View';
    folderShareService.sharedTo = brandAPIName;
    folderShareService.sharedToType = 'Role';
    System.debug('Email Folder :::::: '+folder);
    folder.folderShares.add(folderShareService);        
    service.updateMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { folder });
```

I tried comparing the two debug logs statements and it shows that folder.folderShares is coming up as empty for the Email Folder and not for the Dashboard Folder and I am not sure why that it.

Debug log statements as printed

```
 DashboardFolder:[Folder.accessType=null, Folder.folderShares=null, Folder.name=null, Folder.publicFolderAccess=null, Folder.sharedTo=null, Metadata.fullName=null, accessType=null, accessType_type_info=(accessType, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field_order_type_info=(fullName, accessType, folderShares, name, publicFolderAccess, sharedTo), folderShares=(FolderShare:[accessLevel=Manage, accessLevel_type_info=(accessLevel, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field_order_type_info=(accessLevel, sharedTo, sharedToType), sharedTo=madhurima.bhowmick@qunomedical.com, sharedToType=User, sharedToType_type_info=(sharedToType, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), sharedTo_type_info=(sharedTo, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false)]), folderShares_type_info=(folderShares, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), fullName=Thirty_Two_Account, fullName_type_info=(fullName, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), name=Thirty Two Account, name_type_info=(name, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), publicFolderAccess=null, publicFolderAccess_type_info=(publicFolderAccess, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), sharedTo=null, sharedTo_type_info=(sharedTo, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), type=DashboardFolder, type_att_info=(xsi:type)]

 EmailFolder:[Folder.accessType=null, Folder.folderShares=null, Folder.name=null, Folder.publicFolderAccess=null, Folder.sharedTo=null, Metadata.fullName=null, accessType=null, accessType_type_info=(accessType, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field_order_type_info=(fullName, accessType, folderShares, name, publicFolderAccess, sharedTo), folderShares=null, folderShares_type_info=(folderShares, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), fullName=null, fullName_type_info=(fullName, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), name=null, name_type_info=(name, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), publicFolderAccess=null, publicFolderAccess_type_info=(publicFolderAccess, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), sharedTo=null, sharedTo_type_info=(sharedTo, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), type=EmailFolder, type_att_info=(xsi:type)]
```